# Chromium-Based Browsers Displaying Blank Pages Only + Pages Appear Briefly When Frozen On An Onn Pro 11" Tablet Running Android 13

Tags: chrome-for-android, webview

I have a new Onn Pro 11" Tablet running Android 13; I just set it up last night, but never bothered to open Chrome. Now, I need to run a Chrome-specific plugin and have discovered that all web services "Running on Chrome" ("Chrome", "Chrome Beta", "Brave", "Google News") are not painting the pages — they appear to be loading somewhere because, sometimes if I can get Chrome to freeze, it'll appear momentarily.

- Tried resetting App Data for all browsers + WebView.
- Tried making sure all System's apps have all permissions, some were missing.
- Tried restarting the Android device several times in-between other tries.
- Tried contacting Google support and he was stumped.
- Tried updating and everything is latest.
- Tried everything I could imagine.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. The screenshot below is what pages look like in Dark mode; turns White in Light mode:

[image: blank Chrome page]